# Restart nginx with jenkins

Tags: node.js, nginx, jenkins

I have set up a freestyle project in Jenkins to run my NodeJS application and I'm using the shell script as below,

```
cd client
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm run build

cd ../server
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

export BUILD_ID=dontKillMePlease

pm2 start server.js --name=timetuner

sudo service nginx reload
```

Error we get ->

```
+ sudo service nginx reload
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Also we have updated the sudoers file as follows

```
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty,!lecture
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Appreciate quick help! Thanks in advance.